# How can I send two attributes through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this ajax that sends an attribute to another page:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data1', function(){  
           var employee_id1 = $(this).attr("Id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch1",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id1:employee_id1},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){
                $('#IdTab1').val(data.IdTab);
                $('#CodigoUtente3').val(data.CodigoUtente1);                     
                $('#Reavaliacao1').prop("checked", data.Reavaliacao);
                $('#Inferior1').prop("checked", data.Inferior); 
                $('#Igual1').prop("checked", data.Igual);
                $('#Superior1').prop("checked", data.Superior);
                $('#employee_id1').val(data.Id);  
                $('#insert2').val("Gravar");  
                $('#add_data_Modal2').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

on the other page you get the value of employee_id1 as shown in the image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUQvI.png)

Now I need to send another attribute besides this one that you are sending, how can I do it?

I'm trying like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data1', function(){  
           var employee_id1 = $(this).attr("Id"); 
           var employee_id11 = $(this).attr("IdTab"); 
           $.ajax({  
                url:"./fetch1",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id1:employee_id1},
                data1:{employee_id11:employee_id11},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data,data1){
                $('#IdTab1').val(data.IdTab);
                $('#CodigoUtente3').val(data.CodigoUtente1);                     
                $('#Reavaliacao1').prop("checked", data.Reavaliacao);
                $('#Inferior1').prop("checked", data.Inferior); 
                $('#Igual1').prop("checked", data.Igual);
                $('#Superior1').prop("checked", data.Superior);
                $('#employee_id1').val(data.Id);
                $('#employee_id11').val(data1.IdTab);  
                $('#insert2').val("Gravar");  
                $('#add_data_Modal2').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });
```

Sends the first attribute correctly but the second gives this error as shown in the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzd81.png)

Comment: You can send more than one variable in `data:`, you can also put the two variables in an array or object and send that variable.

Comment: I have already solved the problem, I managed to pass the two variables in the same attribute and then on the other page I made the explode in the variable sent, which is employee_id1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add as many data items as you like to the `data` property, just seperate them with a comma.

```
data:{employee_id1:employee_id1, employee_id11:employee_id11},
```

Or you can cut the middle man out and do

```
data:{
        employee_id1: $(this).attr("Id"), 
        employee_id11: $(this).attr("IdTab")
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of key/value pairs and jQuery will do the rest for you:

```
data:{employee_id1:employee_id1,employee_id11:employee_id11},
```